# Text file browser for my GTD system

Tags: text-editors

I'm looking for something similar to [Keepnote](http://rasm.ods.org/keepnote/).  However,  I would like it to just be an easy way to browse the plain text files associated with my GTD system.  I find keepnote a little heavy and need something more barebones and lightweight in terms of interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [**Task Coach**](http://www.taskcoach.org/)?

[image: Task Coach]

..or [**The Guide**](http://theguide.sourceforge.net/)

[image: The Guide]

..or [**PNotes**](http://pnotes.sourceforge.net/)

[image: PNotes]

..or [**RedNotebook**](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/)

[image: RedNotebook]

..or, perhaps, [**Stickies**](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/ss.html)?

[image: Stickies]

They are all also available (as of March 2016) on the [**PortableApps platform**](http://portableapps.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A very popular task manager is [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) which runs in [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).  Because it **is** a text browser it already handles editing files as text in the format **you** want, it's a great way to implement GTD.  The online pages have external references to [getting things done](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html) using org-mode.